# How to search for a dataframe value in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. There heads are like this:
[image]

I want to remove the rows from df2 which don't contain df1 company names (substrings).
How do I do that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [**`.str.count()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) of `df1.COMPANY` substrings in `df2.COMPANY` to create a boolean mask:

```py
mask = df2.COMPANY.str.count('|'.join(df1.COMPANY.values)).astype(bool)
df2 = df2[mask]
```

Comment: in case if substring is in df2, how do I handle it?

Comment: @KawaiKx sorry I don't understand. I thought you wanted to remove the row if substring is in `df2`?

Comment: yes, it worked fine. in a different scenario, I have longer COMPANY strings in df1. but requirement is same as before that I want to remove the rows from df2 which don't contain df1 company names . How do I do that?

Comment: @KawaiKx ohh remove rows which *don't* contain df1 companies? for that you can use `df2 = df2[~mask]`, or maybe I'm misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to inner join the dataframes:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='COMPANY', how='inner')
```

Please check the documentation here for merging:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: no. it didn't work. strings in df1 are substrings for df2.